# java rest webservice to access static resources from salesforce

Tags: java, web-services, rest, salesforce

Is there any way to access static resources from salesforce using java rest webservices?

I have the static resource URL with me. I am not sure how to connect through java rest webservice.

```
String queryURL = "<myURL>";
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(queryURL);
CloseableHttpClient cl = null;
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
cl = getDefaultHttpClient();
response = cl.execute(getMethod);
```

I am receiving HttpResponseProxy as 302. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Get the enterpise wsdl..
Get the session object
Expose the your functionality as wsdl.

Pass the session through in the required soap call.

Another method 
Expose your Salesforce functionality as rest call. call it using httpclient from your rest app.